# Cannot clear state and getting wrong response from useState form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm strugling with my form in typescript react. Basicly I created 2 simple components `Button` and `Input` and add them to the another component `Form` where I created a whole form.

After submit I should get something like this:

```
telephone: "323423234"
email: "tress@wess.com"
message: "weklfnwlkf"
name: "less"
surname: "mess"
```

But after submit I get weird response like this:

```
"": "323423234"
email: "tress@wess.com"
message: "weklfnwlkf"
name: "less"
surname: "mess"
telephone: ""
```

It is a little bit werido because I done something like this couple days ago and now idk what to do.
There is sample of my `Form` code

```
const Form = () => {
  interface FormDataType {
    telephone: string;
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    email: string;
    message: string;
  }
  const formData: FormDataType = {
    telephone: '',
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  };
  const [responseBody, setResponseBody] = useState<FormDataType>(formData);

  const clearState = () => {
    setResponseBody({ ...formData });
  };

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setResponseBody({ ...responseBody, [name]: value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(responseBody);
    clearState();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {FormData.map((option) => (
          <Input
            key={option.name}
            label={option.label}
            type={option.type}
            className={option.className}
            name={option.name}
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
              handleChange(e)
            }
          />
        ))}
        <div className='div'>
          <Button
            type='submit'
            title={'Simple test'}
            className={'btn-primary'}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

And when I'm invoking in `handleSubmit` function `clearState()` it doesn't refresh states in webpage inputs.

Comment: What does `FormData` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what it needs, I made some changes, but you can adapt it to your project

```
export default function App() {
  interface FormDataType {
    telephone: string;
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    email: string;
    message: string;
  }
  const formData: FormDataType = {
    telephone: "",
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    email: "",
    message: ""
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState<FormDataType | any>(formData);

  // reset
  const reset = (newFormState = formData) => {
    setValues(newFormState);
  };

  // handleInputChange
  const handleInputChange = ({ target }: any) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [target.name]: target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(values);
    reset();
  };

  const data = [
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "name"
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "surname"
    },
    {
      type: "email",
      name: "email"
    },
    {
      type: "tel",
      name: "telephone"
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "message"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {data.map((option) => (
          <input
            key={option.name}
            value={values[option.name]}
            type={option.type}
            name={option.name}
            placeholder={option.name}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        ))}
        <div className="div">
          <button type="submit">Simple test</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reset doesn't work because your inputs are [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

To have them reset properly, you should make them controlled by passing them a `value` prop. It would look something like this:

```
<Input
  key={option.name}
  label={option.label}
  type={option.type}
  className={option.className}
  name={option.name}
  value={responseBody[option.name]} // Add this
  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    handleChange(e)
  }
/>
```

This will connect the `responseBody` form data with the input values.

As to the odd console logged value, it would appear that at least one of the `option.name` values is empty/undefined (looks like the telephone object). Verify that the `FormData` contains complete and correct values.